# Kernel does not exist in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have already developed project in laravel and i'm setting up it in my local computer but after running `php artisan serve` i'm getting this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\translate\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:788
```

I don't know what is wrong but I have tried everything that I have found on internet

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload
composer self-update
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

none of that command worked for me

Comment: Please share more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run `composer install` for installing the new dependencies.

Since you mentioned that you have issues with your other artisan commands delete everything inside the bootstrap->cache folder, except of the `.gitignore` file of course,  manually and then run `php artisan optimize`

That way your "corrupted" cache will be recreated and reconfigured.

First thing you must do is to make sure your artisan commands are working right, so do the caching fix i suggest first. Then you can run the composer commands you mentioned also in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have this file in `app/Console` folder

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        /*$schedule->command('users:update')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('servers:update')->everyMinute();*/
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i have the same file Kernel.php in app/console folder

Comment: About the commands you listed in your post, do they trigger any error or not?

Comment: ```php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear``` This two commands give me the same error

Comment: Then remove manually all the `bootstrap/cache` folder content (without deleting the folder itself)

Comment: after deleting the content of cache folder should  i run any other command instead of ```php artisan serve```?

Comment: I have no more ideas tbh